# VST Plug-In: How to implement a "lookahead" buffer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sox, vst, audacity

My goal is to write a [**VST**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) plug-in that should work in *Audition* and *Audacity*, so I'm planning to go with VST v2.x. I'm new to VST development, but I have studied the examples [**here**](http://www.gersic.com/vstsdk/html/plug/2.0/examples.html). And so far most stuff looks pretty straight forward. The main "magic" seems to happen in the **process()** or **processReplace()** function. Not quite sure what is the benefit/drawback of these two functions though.

Now the "problem" is that my filter is going to need a "Lookahead" buffer of a few seconds (maybe longer, depends on setup). This means that, at the beginning of the process, I will need to fill my *internal* buffer. And, at the end of the process, I will need to flush the pending samples from the *internal* buffer.

I have been coding filters for [**SoX**](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (Sound eXchange) before and their API is pretty similar to VST at a first glance. What is called **process()** in VST, is called **flow()** in SoX API. But there's one major difference: The **flow()** function in SoX API gets, as parameters, the number of samples available in the *input* buffer as well as the number of samples that fit into the *output* buffer. The **flow()** function then returns the number of samples it has taken from the *input* buffer as well as the number of samples it has written into the *output* buffer. It means I don't have to process all available input samples in every call. And a single call can return fewer samples than it has consumed. Consequently, at the beginning of the process, I can consume all *input* samples but return **no** *output* samples at all! This way I can fill my "lookahead" buffer at the beginning. Finally, SoX API has a **drain()** function that will be called by the Main application at the end of the process in order to flush the pending samples from the filter's *internal* buffer.

From what I understand about VST, the **process()** function only has a single parameter to indicate the number of *input* and *output* samples. And it has no way to limit the number of output samples. Apparently, **process()** assumes a simple "N samples in, N samples out" behavior. Is that right ???

If so, what is the recommended way to fill my *internal* lookahead buffer in VST? And what is the recommended way to flush  my *internal* buffer at the end in VST?

---

BTW: I know that I could, of course, fill my internal buffer by returning only "silence" in the first several **process()** calls, at the beginning of the process. But that would delay/shift the entire audio file, which is **not** wanted! Also it does **not** solve the problem how to flush the internal buffer at the end of the process.

Thank you for any advices! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured out a solution. There is a **setInitialDelay()** function in VST. So I guess I'll need to delay the output myself and then compensate by setting the proper value by **setInitialDelay()**.

**[UPDATE]**

This seems to work nice with *Audition*,  but **not** with *Audacity*. Looks like *Audacity* ignores the value set by **setInitialDelay()**, so audio ends up delayed. Is there any workaround for *Audacity* ???